# How do I animate a collectionView without the cells moving?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to create a collectionView which slides up when the user swipes up. For now I am using a button instead of the scroll gesture to trigger the animation. When the animation Begins I want the collectionView to expand in height but the cells to stay where they are and then as the user scrolls slide up. How do I animate the collectionView without moving the cells? Is this possible to do? I would like for the collectionView to expand up and show the hidden cells that were covered up during the scroll not or show a blank space from the collectionView not just move all of the cells higher on the screen.

Function of Code in Question

```
var buttonPressed:Bool = true
@IBAction func changeView(_ sender: Any) {
    if buttonPressed{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05){
        self.animateCollectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 600, height: 1000)
     //   self.animateCollectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -20)
        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: self.animateCollectionView)
        self.buttonPressed = !self.buttonPressed
        print("Ive been expanded")
    }
    }
    else{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05){
            self.animateCollectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: 600, height: 1000)
           // self.animateCollectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 20)
            self.buttonPressed = !self.buttonPressed
        }
    }
}
```

Code as whole:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 200
    }

    var counter:Int = 0
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = self.animateCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! customCell
        counter+=1
        cell.cellLabel.text = "\(counter)"
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        return cell
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var animateCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        animateCollectionView.dataSource = self
        animateCollectionView.delegate = self
        animateCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        animateCollectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 600, height: 1000)
         self.view.sendSubview(toBack: self.animateCollectionView)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    var buttonPressed:Bool = true
    @IBAction func changeView(_ sender: Any) {
        if buttonPressed{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05){
            self.animateCollectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 600, height: 1000)
         //   self.animateCollectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -20)
            self.view.sendSubview(toBack: self.animateCollectionView)
            self.buttonPressed = !self.buttonPressed
            print("Ive been expanded")
        }
        }
        else{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05){
                self.animateCollectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: 600, height: 1000)
               // self.animateCollectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 20)
                self.buttonPressed = !self.buttonPressed
            }
        }
    }

}

class customCell :UICollectionViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var cellLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what you're talking about. In your description, I think you are going to expand a collection view from a smaller one to a bigger one animatedly. But looking at your code, I think you're going to move a fixed size collection view around without moving its content. The former is easy to implement, which you only need to animate its height. The latter is also can be implement.

Comment: You can make the frame of your collection view have a bigger size than the size of its display field, then use the mask property of the collection view's layer to trim its display content, and move the mask with your button event. This should fulfill your needs.

Comment: @Turtleeeeee Thank you for your response, What I am trying to do is expand the height and shift upwards the collectionView frame without shifting the position of the cells inside of the collection while the animation is taking place. I couldn't find the property within the collectionView to change the size of the display field of the cells. Thank you for your help.

Comment: UICollectionView has a property named layer. It’s of CALayer class, and CALayer has a property named mask, which is also a CALayer. Usually it’s nil, you can allocate a layer and set it to the collection view layer mask. The display field of your collection view will be where your mask laid in.

Comment: @Turtleeeeee Thank you again for your response, I tried playing around with the CGLayer and adding a mask but the mask just seems to cover the cells and move up and down with the entire collectionView. How would I make the cells remain stationary while the collectionView slides up using the mask if it moves with the collectionView?

Comment: You can try changing the frame of the mask to move the mask instead of moving the entire collection view. See if this could satisfy you.

Comment: @Turtleeeeee Thank you for all of your help, it is of great assistance. When I put the mask inside the frame of the `collectionView` it blocks the cells from the user making them unaccessible. Is it possible to create mask which sits inside the top of the collectionView but doesn't block the cells perhaps there is a way to shift the cells below the masked part of the collectionView.